# Incorrect recovery in Rabin's IDA (Information Dispersal Algorithm)

Tags: python, security

I've been trying to create the Rabin's IDA model
Mostly it work correctly, but after recovery i have a little deviations from the original data
Why is it?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from Crypto.Random import get_random_bytes
np.printoptions(Supress=True)

def dispersal(f, m=4, n=8):
    s_list = [f[i:i+m] for i in range(0, len(f), len(f)//m)]
    s_list_new = [int.from_bytes(s, byteorder='big') for s in s_list]
    random_elements = np.random.choice(range(1, 256), n, replace=False)
    vander_matrix = np.vander(random_elements, m, increasing=True)
    result_operator = vander_matrix @ s_list_new
    print(result_operator)
    return result_operator, vander_matrix

def recovery(f_list, vander_matrix, m=4, n=8):
    vander_inv = np.linalg.inv(vander_matrix)
    M = vander_inv @ f_list
    print(M)
    return M

f = get_random_bytes(32)
print(f)
disp_result, vander_matrix = dispersal(f)
disp_list = disp_result[1::2]
vander_matrix_ = vander_matrix[1::2]
recov = recovery(disp_list, vander_matrix_)
```

In original I have this data:

```
b'3\x1e\xd9m\x95o\x83\xe4\x84\xa5\x9f\x03\xb9s\xb8\xd6\x0b\xf1*\xc9ko\x1a\x1b@K\xeaf\xaa\x86=\x9d'
s_list:  [857659757, 2225446659, 200354505, 1078717030]
```

And after recovery I got:

```
[8.57659758e+08 2.22544666e+09 2.00354505e+08 1.07871703e+09]

print(recov[0])

>> 857659758.375
```